# Add olympus-camerakit tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation-process

Olympus announced a new interchangeable-lens camera AIR A01, which can be controlled via Wi-Fi. Its communication protocol and API libraries for iOS and Android are opened for everyone.

Olympus assumes that users discuss on programming issues on SO with `olympus-camerakit` tag, but it seems that there is no such a tag. 
How to Use Stack Overflow on Olympus Page:
http://opc.olympus-imaging.com/en_sdkdocs/data/inquiry/inquiry.html#stackoverflow

I don't have enough reputation, so could anyone add `olympus-camerakit` tag?

Now a few developers including me post questions using tags like ios, swift, and so on. The users of Olympus' SDK are difficult to find related questions to the SDK from huge amount of ios/android-tagged question. There is an olympus-air tag but I think this is camera's name and not appropriate to SDK question. Sony have already opened similar API to control wireless camera and the users use `sony-camera-api` tag.

My posted question on the SDK: 
[Olympus Camera Kit: App exits when it draws face detection frame on the live view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931317/)

Olympus also announces to post question with title including a keyword "Olympus Camera Kit" if he/she don't have enough reps to make a tag, so you can find some questions with the keyword above.

Tag description (copy from Olympus' web site)

Olympus Camera Kit is the Software Development Kit (SDK) for OLYMPUS Open Platform Cameras (OPCs). You can easily develop applications to control a camera via wireless communication.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that Olympus has people on SO answering questions, I'm a little surprised they didn't add the tag themselves. Makes me wonder if they really intend to field questions here...

[I went ahead and added the tag for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31931317/1947286) Hope it works out.

Comment: It looks like [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4922953/opc-support) is, in fact, the Olympus people trying to answer questions on SO.

Comment: @ashes999 Should their about be in English since this is an English site?

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't know. I see that their answers are. Asking users to change their profile is probably not something we can easily do (or that they are required to comply with).

Comment: I got one, not terribly helpful answer from Olympus to a question I posted using your tag. Thanks for adding it.   I cannot download the SDK at the toolssdk url.  Every time I fill in the request form to download it, I get redirected back to the toolssdk url.  Can anyone else get the SDK at the moment.  I really want the HTTP protocol doc most, but it would be great to get anything as my camera has arrived and I can't do anything with it at this point.